# what is contract and what is vote?

Tags: ether, wallets

I know this is too easy for all of you to answer, but I am really struggling with the terms.

I understand that Etherium is a platform where application can be ran against some fees (ethers). but what does it have to do with contracts and votes?

After each article I read, I get more confused as new terms come up in every line.

My main goal is I am programming an ico page and I need to create etherium addresses programmatically. but the two questions above will help me understand the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart contracts are the "applications" that run on Ethereum.

I don't think that "votes" have anything to do with Ethereum. My guess would be that you're reading an article that talks about using a smart contract to implement some sort of voting? Hard to say without knowing what you're reading.

Comment: yeah I was reading this article: https://www.ethereum.org/dao . Now as I understand, contract ist just an application that triggers certain actions depending on the contraints. example case: I am selling a chewing gum on etherium. I will write a smart contract in solidity that defines how much one chewing gum costs. if someone sends me 1 ether for example, automatically he will get one chewing gum, hence a purchase contract happened right here. am I going into right direction?

Comment: That's sort of right. (Of course, a smart contract can't send anyone chewing gum.)

Answer (score 1):

While researching Ethereum. I found the Udemy.com courses (which are inexpensive) provide an outstanding wealth of knowledge for understanding Ethereum, Blockchain and Solidity. Easy to follow, to the point and no fluff to wade through.

Comment: It should be good if you can add the name of the course you have followed.

Comment: Absolutely Ismael,  I found the following useful. Solidity Programming for Beginners. Ethereum & Solidity: The Complete Developer's Guide. How to Set Up Smart Contracts and Ethereum Developer Masterclass.